# Как проверить тип ошибки при использовании fs в nodejs

Tags: json, node.js, fs, parse

Я с помощью fs в nodejs открываю файл. С помощью try/catch. И если выполняется JSON.parse() по данным из файла, то все ок, если нет - ошибка(catch). Как проверить в catch когда ошибка - файл не найден, а когда ошибка из за не выполнения JSON.parse(). Т.е. данные в файле не в JSON формате?

Код открытия файла: `const data = fs.readFileSync('file.json', 'utf8');`

Comment: Полезно будет привести ваш код для тех, кто захочет помочь. Например, важно, используете вы синхронное открытие файла или асинхронное, а в асинхронном используете промисы или колбеки.

Comment: можно просто вывести какая ошибка пришла и проверить

Comment: Вы можете обернуть в два разных блока  try/catch сначала открытие файла, потом парсинг JSON, так в каждом catch будет относительно однозначная ошибка.

Comment: Ну или проверять свойства объекта ошибки. Изучите, какие они в каждом случае, и проверяйте в общем catch.

Comment: @vsemozhebuty Поставьте как ответ, я приму.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно, например, так:

```js
const fs = require('fs');

let data;

try {
  data = fs.readFileSync('test.json', 'utf8');
} catch {
  console.error('fs error!');
}

if (data) {
  try {
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(data);
  } catch {
    console.error('JSON error!');
  }
}
```

Или так:

```js
const fs = require('fs');

try {
  let data = fs.readFileSync('test.json', 'utf8');
  data = JSON.parse(data);
  console.log(data);
} catch(err) {
  if (err.code === 'ENOENT') console.error('fs error!');
  else if (err instanceof SyntaxError) console.error('JSON error!');
  else console.error('Unknown error: ', err);
}
```